# Display a php calculated value and pass it to database

Tags: php, html, sql

I guess it is a simple function & I am missing the coding somewhere. Looking for a help.

I get the user's input date & adding/calculating working days to it. The php code works & display when I retrieve the inputs from Database. But I want to calculate the days when user gives the input & pass it to database via submit button.

Here is my coding. Pls help

```
<?php
include_once('confiq.php');

// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

// Connect to MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'fiber' );

// Check our connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// Insert our data
$sql = "INSERT INTO fiberexcel ( SiteID0, SiteName1, SiteAddress2, ProjectType3, ReqDate4, TargetDate5, Vendor6, ESRNo7, Contact8, Engineer9, AM10 ) 
VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['SiteID0'])}', 
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['SiteName1'])}' , 
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['SiteAddress2'])}', 
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ProjectType3'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ReqDate4'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['TargetDate5'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Vendor6'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ESRNo7'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Contact8'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Engineer9'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['AM10'])}')";

$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
// Print response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
echo "!";
} else {
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}
// Close our connection
$mysqli->close();
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Customer</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="css/layout1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="home"><a href="index.html"><img src="./img/home.png"></img></a>
</div>
<h2><u>CREATE CUSTOMER</u></h2>
<form action="Create.php" method="post">
<table border="0" align="left" cellspacing="30" height="5">
<tr><td><b>Site ID:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="SiteID0" name="SiteID0" size="35" required="required"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Site Name:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="SiteName1" name="SiteName1" size="35" required="required"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Site Address:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="SiteAddress2" name="SiteAddress2" size="35" required="required"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Project Type:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="ProjectType3" name="ProjectType3" size="35"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Requested Date:</b></td> <td><input type="date" id="ReqDate4" name="ReqDate4" size="35"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Target Completion Date</b></td> 
<td><input type="date" id="TargetDate5"
<?php 
$ReqDate4= date("Y-m-d"); //increment 75 days 
$TargetDate5 = strtotime($ReqDate4."+ 75 weekday"); 
echo date("Y-m-d",$TargetDate5) . "\n"; 
echo "</td>"; 
$_POST['$TargetDate5 ']=$TargetDate5 ; 
echo "</td>";
;?>
<br></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Vendor:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="Vendor6" name="Vendor6" size="35" required="required"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>ESR No:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="ESRNo7" name="ESRNo7" size="35" ><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Contact Details:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="Contact8" name="Contact8" size="35" ><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Engineer:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="Engineer9" name="Engineer9" size="35" required="required"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Account Manager:</b></td> <td><input type="text" id="AM10" name="AM10" size="35" ><br></td></tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action" /></td>
<td><input type ="submit" value="Clear" onclick="reset();"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    function emergencyleavecomp(){

document.getElementById("startDate").value = "";
document.getElementById("endDate").value = "";
document.getElementById("count").value = "";


      document.getElementById("remain_leave").value = "";
      document.getElementById("calculate").value = "";
      document.getElementById("Used_Leave").value = "";
      document.getElementById("sickleave").checked = false;
      // document.getElementById("emergencyleave").checked = false;
      document.getElementById("paternityleave").checked = false;
      document.getElementById("maternityleave").checked = false;
      document.getElementById("compasionateleave").checked = false;
      document.getElementById("vacationleave").checked = false;
      var emerleave = document.getElementById("emergencyleave");
// 
      // document.getElementById("vacationleave").checked = false;
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
      //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
      }
      if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
      }
      today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
      // document.write(today);
      var checkcategory = (document.getElementById("checkcategory").value);
      // var vacay = document.getElementById("vacationleave");

// 
      if(emerleave.checked){
        var emeval = document.getElementById("foremergencyleave").value;
        document.getElementById("Used_Leave").value = emeval;

        if(checkcategory == "Local"){
           $('#startDate').on('change',function(){
          var probDate=new Date(document.getElementById("forcomputeleave").value);
          var nowDate= new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
          var timeDiff=Math.abs(probDate.getTime()-nowDate.getTime());
          var diffDays=Math.ceil(timeDiff/(1000*3600*24));
          // document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = diffDays;
          var calc = Math.round((diffDays * 0.0416666666666667)*100)/100;
          document.getElementById("calculate").value = calc;
          var remain = Math.round((calc - document.getElementById("Used_Leave").value)*100)/100;
          document.getElementById("remain_leave").value = remain;
          });
        }
        else{
           $('#startDate').on('change',function(){
          var probDate=new Date(document.getElementById("forcomputeleave").value);
          var nowDate= new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
          var timeDiff=Math.abs(probDate.getTime()-nowDate.getTime());
          var diffDays=Math.ceil(timeDiff/(1000*3600*24));
          // document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = diffDays;
          var calc = Math.round((diffDays * 0.0833333333333333)*100)/100;
          document.getElementById("calculate").value = calc;
          var remain = Math.round((calc - document.getElementById("Used_Leave").value)*100)/100;
          document.getElementById("remain_leave").value = remain;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

You can edit this code to what you want to do. This computes from dates to another. If that's what your asking for.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not my request. The "Requested date" field will be given by the user. I want to add days to that input, display it in the "TagetDate" field & pass the calculated Date value to database. I have a different page for Displaying the user inputs in a table. There the calculation works only in the page, not stored in database. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **name="TargetDate5"** in '**Target Completion Date**' field so it is not getting posted in your $_POST array.
Also, below values are not posted from form but its present in your query.

```
$_POST['ESRNo7']
$_POST['Contact8']
$_POST['Engineer9']
$_POST['AM10']
```

Comment: $ReqDate4= date("Y-m-d");
 //increment 75 days
$TargetDate5 = strtotime($ReqDate4."+ 75 weekday");
echo date("Y-m-d",$TargetDate5) . "\n";
echo "</td>";
$_POST['$TargetDate5 ']=$TargetDate5 ; // This POST function is not working. The calculate value does not display in the page or does not store in the database. Pls help

Comment: Yes. I did not add that code here. Shall I add the entire code?

Comment: First check if all the data in $_POST array is defined or posted in Create.php (the ones which is used in query) , then print your query and run it directly in phpmyadmin and see what is going wrong.See if that helps

Comment: You mean there is a undefined index? Rest of the codings are ok?